# Different GCM Registration ID on a device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to get different Registration ID on a device for every user that logins in my application and handle different notification for different users,How?

Answer (score 3):

Actually if you unregister GCM and register for a new user, even if you get a new registration id, the old one will still work. When you push to the old one,  you'll get in the response a canonical registration id, whose value is the new registration id. That's Google's way of telling your server to use only the latest registration id, but old registration ids keep on working for a long time.

Therefore,  when the user logs out, you must call your server and delete the old registration id from your db.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `unregister()` method on your logout button. This will invalidate the registration ID.

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#unregister%28%29) for more details.

Comment: you say it invalidates the registration ID,so the GCM Server won't send notification to previous registration ID,it will?

Comment: But that is what you want. Don't you? Because at any time in your application only one person can be logged in (Hope this is what you want), so only one person can receive the notification.

Comment: No I didn't mean it,I wanted to keep previous Registration ID and get a new one and send notification to both of them.